# Vue-material stepper : Check input content to handle md-continue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-material

I'm trying to use vue-material stepper to make a multi-step form, and I want to check input validity to allow the continue action.
I see in the documentation that I can disable "Continue" button with a boolean value in md-continue like this :

```
<md-stepper md-vertical>
      <md-step md-label="Etape 1/5" md-message="Vos coordonnées"
        md-button-continue="Continuer"
        md-button-back="Revenir"
        :md-continue="false">
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Civilite</label>
          <md-input id="civilite"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Nom</label>
          <md-input id="nom"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Prénom</label>
          <md-input id="prenom"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Email</label>
          <md-input id="email"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Téléphone (ex: 0472383254)</label>
          <md-input id="telephone"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
      </md-step>
      <md-step md-label="Etape 2/5" md-message="Type d'enquête à diligenter">
        <strong>Périmètre</strong>
      </md-step>
    </md-stepper>
```

But I want to check in every input change if all input are correct, then return true in the md-continue.
Is there a way to make the md-continue change with a method that check inputs validity ?
Thanks

**EDIT (answer to Phil) :**

```
<template>
  <form method="post" class="enqueteForm">
    <md-stepper md-vertical>
      <md-step md-label="Etape 1/5" md-message="Vos coordonnées"
        md-button-continue="Continuer"
        md-button-back="Revenir"
        :md-continue="step1valid">
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Civilite</label>
          <md-input id="civilite" @change="validStep1"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Nom</label>
          <md-input id="nom"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Prénom</label>
          <md-input id="prenom"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Email</label>
          <md-input id="email"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
        <md-input-container>
          <label>Téléphone (ex: 0472383254)</label>
          <md-input id="telephone"></md-input>
        </md-input-container>
      </md-step>
      <md-step md-label="Etape 2/5" md-message="Type d'enquête à diligenter">
        <strong>Périmètre</strong>
      </md-step>
    </md-stepper>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'enquete-dialog',
    components: {},
    props: {
      step1valid: Boolean,
    },
    data: {
      step1valid: false,
    },
    methods: {
      validStep1() {
        if (document.querySelector('#civilite').getAttribute('value') !== null) {
          this.step1valid = true;
        }
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, bind it to a data value / computed property / method in your component / instance

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for your answer.
I tried to make it with just one input verification to test, the "Continue" button is now disabled but the method validStep1() don't enable the button when "civilite" input change.
I edit my first message to show you the code

Comment: Finally it's working, it was an error in my code, thanks Phil !